# make with directories as pattern drops intermediate files?

Tags: makefile

I have the following  Makefile:

```
cells.csv: 
        echo cellA >  cells.csv
        echo cellB >> cells.csv
        echo cellC >> cells.csv
        echo cellD >> cells.csv
        mkdir -p cellA
        mkdir -p cellB
        mkdir -p cellC
        mkdir -p cellD


%/cell_gen: cells.csv
        echo '$@ generated' >  $@

%/cell_gds: %/cell_gen
        cat   $(@D)/cell_gen  >  $@
        echo  $@_GDS          >> $@
```

The idea is to generate 'cells' in two step (called [cell]_gen and [cell]_gds) while the cells list is
not known at the beginning of make.
 Here: the target 'cells.csv' is human readable (just echo) , but in 
the general case, I expect something complexe, itselft resulting of previous steps ...etc..: not readable.
Each step of 'cell' should be stored in the directory named [cell] .
I don't understand why in this case, if I ask for "make cellA/cell_gds" then it looks like
the steps are all executed: I get the csv file and I get cellA/cell_gds.
...but I can't explain why I don't get cellA/cell_gen  ??
... Despite I can see "echo 'cellA/cell_gen generated' >  cellA/cell_gen" during make execution , 
 and i really get "cellA/cell_gen generated" instide the cellA/cell_gds
Does anybody knows why there is no file cellA/cell_gen ?? 
thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The file `cellA/cell_gen` is an [intermediate file](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules); you didn't explicitly ask for it, Make deduced that it was necessary as part of a chain of pattern rules. So by default, Make will delete it once the "real" target, `cellA/cell_gds`, is complete.

To prevent this, just add the line

```
.PRECIOUS: %/cell_gen
```

Comment: It'd be probably safer to use `.SECONDARY`. Using `.PRECIOUS` keeps `make` from deleting the file if interrupted, which may not be a good thing.

Comment: @Idelic: Yes, but for some reason I couldn't get it to work (with GNUMake 3.81). I'd rather offer an imperfect solution than one I can't verify at all.